# How to set up mesos for running spark on standalone OS/X

Tags: macos, scala, apache-spark, mesos

I want to do testing of Spark programs on a Mac. Spark is running and my spark scala program compiles: but there is a library (*mesos*.so ?) error at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mesos in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at org.apache.mesos.MesosNativeLibrary.load(MesosNativeLibrary.java:46)
    at spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:170)
    at com.blazedb.scala.ccp.spark.LoadRDD$.main(LoadRDD.scala:14)
```

What setup is required on os/x beyond the spark server itself for mesos in order to run a spark client program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use Spark with Mesos, there are [instructions on the project website](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html), including notes on how to find the path to the Mesos library on OS X.

As you've noticed, there are [other deployment modes](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html), including the `local` modes, that don't require Mesos to be installed.

Based on your stacktrace, it looks like you might be using an older version of Spark.  Since Spark 0.8.0+, the packages have been moved into the `org.apache.spark` namespace, so you might need to use [earlier versions of the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html) if you don't want to upgrade.

Answer (score 9):

You need to set 'MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY' environment variable, which is the location of libmesos.so. It's typically /usr/local/lib/libmesos.so.

```
# For Linux
$ export MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY='/usr/local/lib/libmesos.so'

# For OSX
$ export MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY='/usr/local/lib/libmesos.dylib'
```

I would recommend adding that line to your .bashrc as well, to avoid doing that every time.

Comment: Warning: MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY is deprecated, use MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY instead. Future releases will not support JNI bindings via MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY.

Answer (score 2):

if you build mesos from sources then all generated libs will be generated inside [MESOS_HOME]/src/.libs folder. You must delete the empty [MESOS_HOME]/.libs folder and create symbolic link to [MESOS_HOME]/src/.libs

Used commands are:

- rm -r [MESOS_HOME]/src/.libs
- ln -s [MESOS_HOME]/src/.libs [MESOS_HOME]/.libs

lost my problem "g++: error: ./.libs/libmesos.so: No such file or directory"