# How can I compile libmesos.so file?

Tags: apache, compilation, elasticsearch, mesos

I have been working on elasticsearch on mesos. I want to setup elasticsearch-mesos in my local machine running on ubuntu. I did as per the [documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/) for mesos. Also I setup elasticsearch according to the instructions given [here](https://github.com/mesosphere/elasticsearch-mesos). When I run elasticsearch I am getting an error

```
Failed to load native Mesos library from /home/me/workspace/mesos-  
0.20.1/src/java/generated/org/apache/mesos
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mesos in   
java.library.path
```

After googling for a while I tried changing the path to /usr/local/lib and some other java paths but then I saw that its searchin
I refered to some SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941201/how-to-set-up-mesos-for-running-spark-on-standalone-os-x) but I could not find libmesos.so anywhere in the mesos directory or in my filesystem but I found libmesos.la. Can I compile libmesos.so from libmesos.la?

Answer (score 0):

Download [this](https://googleclusterdata.googlecode.com/archive/4f891eb08833ff722ecfd2fb126ef8ca52aef6ab.tar.gz.) file and extract it. You will find a compiled libmesos.so file. Copy it to some location like /usr/local/lib and edit your mesos.yml to make java.library.path point to that file. Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I tried the above fix. Now I am getting another error. 
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff83e196b87, pid=8891, tid=140703811970816
. I think compiled libmesos.so is creating issues. How can I  compile libmesos.so in my local machine?

Comment: Try building once more as per the [Getting started] guide of mesos. It will create libmesos.so. You may have to provide root privilleges while running make install. [Getting started]: https://mesos.apache.org/getting-started/

Comment: https://googleclusterdata.googlecode.com/archive/4f891eb08833ff722ecfd2fb126ef8ca52aef6ab.tar.gz. is broken @cutteeth

Comment: But the guide says "make install" is optional.

Comment: good pratice would be to never provide an obscure google drive link. This library could be useful for cryptomining no one would know.